# Update a table's column by using a group by

Tags: python, sqlite

I would like to calculate the average in specific column of my table grouping by another column, but it doesn't work, I have a problem whith the group by.

My code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("ma_base.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("UPDATE test_centrale set avg_price = avg(prix) group by test_centrale.version ")
conn.commit()
print('done')
cur.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right. Use subquery to find the second average and update using following query

```
cur.execute("UPDATE test_centrale set avg_price = (select avg(prix) from test_centrale group by test_centrale.version )")
```